# Adding items to menu in material design

Tags: javascript, html, material-design

I have this code for a menu in my html, the options I need to show in the menu are one that are input by the user, so I don't know how to add them. Should I just append everything?

```
<div id="demo-menu" class="mdc-menu-surface--anchor">
        <button class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon mdc-icon-button" aria-label="Open navigation menu">edit</button>
        <div class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface">
          <div class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface">
            <ul class="mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-orientation="vertical" tabindex="-1">
              <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem">
                <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
                <span class="mdc-list-item__text">A Menu Item</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: According to your description, a user must input an option and you want to show it into the menu item. So there is a backend process that saves the data to the database and then you can show it into a menu item. But you didn't share the proper code example. Please provide proper code so that contributors can analyze the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.